# jquery select x elements and addClass to target and child

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Can this be chained to a one liner ? (.text is child of .text-container)

```
$('.text-container:eq(15)').nextAll().addClass('hidden');
$('.text-container:eq(15)').nextAll().find('.text').addClass('hidden');
```

?

Thanks

Comment: If the parent is hidden, the children will automatically be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the modification methods in jQuery are chainable (they return the collection they were applied to), so you can write:

```
$('.text-container:eq(15)').nextAll().addClass('hidden').find(".text").addClass('hidden');
```

Comment: simply beautiful.Thanks Barmar !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to add the class hidden to .text-container:eq(15) and to all of it's children which contain the class text?

If so you can do it like this:

```
$('.text-container:eq(15), .text-container:eq(15) .text').addClass('hidden');
```

Comment: Thanks ! In my code though some childs are skipped, Will need to make a fiddle to figure it out. But you got me right !

Comment: What about `.nextAll()`?

Comment: Indeed : adding nextAll() before addClass() on the oneliner doesnt give me the same behavior than my 2 lines